# Scrape information from meta data with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, meta-tags

I wonder how I can scrape how I can scrape of author affiliation from a page like this:

http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=1701938

The information that I want is stored in a meta-tag that looks like this:

```
<meta name="citation_author_institution" content="Department of Computing Science, University of Alberta">
```

I tried something like this:

```
var affiliation = doc.getElementsByTagName('meta').item(property='citation_author_institution');
```

But this didn't seem to work for me.
Can someone enlighten please

Comment: This works for me in Chrome: `document.getElementsByTagName('meta')['citation_author_institution']`

Comment: Okay, how do you check if it works?
I'm maybe doing something wrong when I check

Comment: Here's a quick demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ak53zyks/

Comment: Okay then it works. Then the problem is probably when I'm trying to put it in the JSON-array that I'm creating.

Comment: Because when I try to scrape and add it to my JSON-array in my program I get the outprint:

[Object HTMLMetaElement], what does that mean?

Comment: That's the element itself (e.g. `document.getElementsByTagName('meta')['citation_author_institution']`) and not one of the properties (e.g. `document.getElementsByTagName('meta')['citation_author_institution'].content` - note the `.content` at the end)

Comment: So you mean that if I write like you did:

document.getElementsByTagName('meta')['citation_author_institution'].content

Instead I would get the content of the element?

Comment: Yes, then you get the content of the property `content`. If it's `<meta name="abc" description="def">` you'd need `document.getElementsByTagName('meta')['abc'].description`

Comment: Thx for the explanation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx to the user Reeno, I finally got the content of this meta tag that I needed. Here is the final code:

```
var affiliation = doc.getElementsByTagName('meta')[property='citation_author_institution'].content;
```